# Laravel access JSON data in PHP controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have this AJAX function, which sends data to a route:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/home/update_user_data',
    type : "post",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data : {'userid' : $('#user-general-i').data('userid'), 'datatype' : datatype, 'newcontent' : newcontent},
    success : function(response) {
        console.log("update_user_data", response);

        if (response['success'] == true) {
            console.log('success');
        } else {

        }
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        console.log("update_user_data", xhr);
    }
});
```

In the route I cant figure out how to access the data, usually I can use `$data->value` but here it does not work. I assume because I dont serialize a form.

Here is how I try to access the data:

```
public function update_user_data(Request $data) {

    try {           
        error_log($data);
        error_log(print_r($data->all(), True));
        error_log($data->query('userid'));
        error_log($data->userid);
        error_log($data->datatype);
        error_log($data->newcontent);  
    } catch (\Exception $e) {  
        return ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];   
    } 

    return ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Konnte Nutzer nicht updaten'];   
}
```

I have red the laravel docu on requests and tried all ways to access the data, but I simply get an empty string, no errors.

BUT `error_log($data);` shows the request and there I can see that the data is there:

```
userid=4777&datatype=gender&newcontent=1
```

**EDIT**

I can get the above string with:

```
error_log($data->getContent());
```

But I cant get specific values, I could use regex to extract them or split the string, but that feels super hacky and wrong.

**EDIT**

I also tried to change the AJAX request:

```
data : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(({'userid' : $('#user-general-i').data('userid'), 'datatype' : datatype, 'newcontent' : newcontent})))
```

I also tried to add:

```
dataType: "json"
```

But sadly nothing changed, all `error_log`are empty.

Laravel Version: Laravel Framework 5.8.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `$data` is the `Request` object not the actual data.

You first need to get data out of the request object.

Try below:

```php
public function update_user_data(Request $request) {
  $data = $request->all();

  // you can now be able to access your data like:
  $data['userid'];
  $data['datatype'];
  $data['newcontent'];
  //...
}
```

Or in the newer versions of Laravel, you can use `request()` global function to get data out from the `Request` object.

```php
request('userid'); // gives you userid passed via ajax i.e `4777`
```

Change your ajax request:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify( {"userid": $('#user-general-i').data('userid')} ),
// ...
```

Comment: Can you show the path of `Request` class you're using?

Comment: This: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`?

Comment: Which laravel version do you use?

Comment: Good, how about using `request()` helper function that  I mentioned in my answer? Give it a try and see.

Comment: I will try now, check my edit please, maybe it helps. Thanks so far for your time.

Comment: Sadly `request('userid')` gives also an empty string

Comment: I updated my answer, modify your ajax request a bit and try

Comment: Thanks, worked. I was close. Only `JSON.stringify()` was needed.